# Inequalities between arbitrary numbers

Tags: functional-inequalities

I was solving an excercise on calculus when i came up with this problem:
Let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ if $a>8-b$ and $a>3$ can it be shown that $b<5$? I've given it some tries but it got me nowhere, could someone propose an idea?

Comment: If $a=4$ and $b=8$, then $a>8-b$ and $a>3$. But $b\not<5$.

Answer (score 1):

We can only do this:
$$3<a>8-b$$
This is not a chain of inequalities. It is not possible to derive a relation between $3$ and $8-b$, so $b<5$ cannot be concluded (we can e.g. take $b=6$ and $a=10$).

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!

Comment: @Nikos127 Please upvote and accept my answer, then.